# Los scroll se me mueven a la hora de firmar

Tags: html5, canvas, firma-digital

Actualmente estoy haciendo una firma digital el cual cuando voy a firmar se me mueve con los scroll he intentado varias veces creo que es problema de css aca tengo un video el cual hice para mostrar el error con detalles
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9ReoLgMZNU&feature=youtu.be

este es mi html5

```
<style type="text/css">


#container{position:relative; margin-left: 10%; }
#container>div {margin-top:10px;}
#container>div:last-child, #respuesta {}
#container label {width:20%;display:inline-block;padding-left:30px;}
#sketchpad{ border: 5px solid #28a745; background-color: #FAFAFA;  }





    </style> 

    <div id="container"> 
      <canvas id="sketchpad" width="320" height="270"> 
        Error no soportado
      </canvas>   
      <div id "datos">
    <table width="320" height="80" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="125" height="30">Cedula:</td>
        <td width="326"><label for="numero"></label>
        <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="26">Nombre:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td height="29"><br><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="salvarDatos();" value="GUARDAR FIRMA" /></td>
        <td height="29"><br><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="borrarDatos();" value="BORRAR FIRMA" /></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Falta el Javascript que utilizaste, pero creo que utilizas eventos táctiles. Cuando utilizas eventos táctiles el comportamiento por defecto de la pantalla es el de hacer scroll. Para que esto no pase necesitas agregar `evento.preventDefault();` Este articulo acerca de [eventos táctiles](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/jsblog/eventos-tactiles.php) te puede ayudar y viene con un ejemplo práctico.

Comment: hola amigo podria yo publicar el codigo y ayudarme con esta parte porfa es que casi no entiendo de canvas

Comment: En el articulo indicado viene un ejemplo funcional de firma digital con eventos táctiles. Echale una mirada.

Answer (score 0):

Añadir esta línea en un evento `touch` es la solución:

```
evento.preventDefault();
```